# How to change 2 words in a string in BASH where there will be a ":" in one of them

Tags: bash, string

I have worked my best on trying to make a script to iterate thorugh 2 Arrays.
The values in each Array needs to get its value input into a string called `ExecuteSyncoid` based on a string called `SyncoidCommand` so a command with the changed parts will be executed.

---

The String is called

```
SyncoidCommand
```

The command/string from `SyncoidCommand` that needs to be changed looks like this

```
SynCoid-IterateThroughDataSets.sh -s /home/darkyere/Scripts/Syncoid/shortsourcelist -d /home/darkyere/Scripts/Syncoid/shortdestinationlist -c "syncoid <username>@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:SourceDataSet DestDataSet --compress none --sshcipher chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com --sshport <Port> --sshkey "/Dest/To/KeyFile" --no-privilege-elevation" -p <Password>
```

Now the two parts that needs to be changed is in

```
<username>@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:SourceDataSet DestDataSet
```

Where `SourceDataSet` and `DestDataSet` is the two in question.

It will in the long run allso need to work in the Opposite way looking like this

```
SourceDataSet <username>@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:DestDataSet
```

---

I have tried these different ways
And  few more i didnt keep in my attempts

The

```
$SourcePath

# And

$DestPath
```

Is the value from the two arrays i am attempting to insert into "ExecuteSyncoid"

```
ExecuteSyncoid="${SyncoidCommand/SourceDataSet/$SourcePath}"  
ExecuteSyncoid="${SyncoidCommand/DestDataSet/$DestPath}"

# ----------


ExecuteSyncoid=$(echo $SyncoidCommand | sed "s+SourceDataSet+$SourcePath+g")
ExecuteSyncoid=$(echo $SyncoidCommand | sed "s+DestDataSet+$DestPath/+g")
```

---

But the changed string allways resembles something like

```
syncoid <username>@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:SourceDataSet Storage/WallaBag --compress none --sshcipher chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com --sshport <Port> --sshkey "/Dest/To/KeyFile" --no-privilege-elevation" -p <Password>
```

So the code changes `DestDataset` without a problem.

But in all my attempts including more than i posted it never changes the

```
<username>@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:SourceDataSet
```

To etc.

```
<username>@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:Storage/WallaBag
```

Is there anyone out there with some bash knowledge that can help me change the part of the string with ":" in it
No matter if it is

```
<username>@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:SourceDataSet DestDataSet

# Or

SourceDataSet <username>@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:DestDataSet
```

Best Regards,
And thank you for reading
Darkyere

EDIT:

This was the error

```
ExecuteSyncoid="${SyncoidCommand/SourceDataSet/$SourcePath}"  
ExecuteSyncoid="${SyncoidCommand/DestDataSet/$DestPath}"
```

This was the fix thanks to Philliphos

```
ExecuteSyncoid="${SyncoidCommand/SourceDataSet/$SourcePath}"  
ExecuteSyncoid2="${SyncoidCommand/DestDataSet/$DestPath}"
```

It was as simple as me overwriting the first string with the second.
After changing the second sting it worked.

Thank you and have a good day.

Comment: As far as I can see, you correctly set `ExecuteSyncoid`, but then overwrite it with the other change. You need to apply both changes to the same input like `ExecuteSyncoid=$(echo $SyncoidCommand | sed "s+SourceDataSet+$SourcePath+g;s+DestDataSet+$DestPath/+g")`

Comment: I might not have explained it well enough.
The origional command is stored in the variable `SyncoidCommand` and then transferred on each change to the variable `ExecuteSyncoid`. So the origional `SyncoidCommand` never changes, only `ExecuteSyncoid`.
So that part should be fine.

Comment: Aaah i see it now. I had to think about what it meant first. I actually overwrite `ExecuteSyncoid` 2 times removing the first change i made. Just by making `ExecuteSyncoid=` and the second as `ExecuteSyncoid2` the second variable have both changes.
Thank you a lot. this helped me getting past this point.